# Visual Studio 2008 Web Project problem with PNG files

Tags: visual-studio

I've added a PNG file to a directory in my VS2k8 webforms project, and when I run the app, it refuses to render my image - it even knows the dimensions but renders a box with a red X.

Oddly enough, if I double click the PNG file within VS2k8, it opens up in the IDE and displays fine (but only within the IDE).

Does anyone have any clues?

The path is correct..  I just have a basic default.aspx page with this in the body

```
  <img src="img/logo.png" />
```

if i navigate to img/logo.png  in the browser, it shows a box with the same dimensions as my image, but a red x.  Its finding the image, just not rendering it.  It's showing up in IE running under the vs2k8 web server  (localhost:5512/default.aspx)

I've dropped a JPG in the same directory, and it shows up just fine.

I'm not sure what type of PNG it is, but here is the kicker....  If i make an HTML file that references that image, copy both this HTML file and PNG file to my webserver (or just double click on the HTML page), it comes up JUST FINE.

Its leading me to believe that the Visual Studio web server may not recognize PNG files (at least this one) properly?

Comment: You mean that you have a web page, and in that web page, you have an `<img />` tag which points to the PNG image, right? Try right clicking the image, see the full image path, and open it in a new browser window.

Comment: Post the HTML code of the page which is shown in the browser.

Comment: What browser are you using?  What is the url in the address bar, and what is the src of the image when you view source?

Comment: What kind of PNG is it? Is it 8bpp? 24bpp? 24bpp plus alpha channel? PNG is a very flexible format that has many features that aren't supported by all implementations. Maybe you could try running the ImageMagick "identify" tool on your PNG and see what it tells you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the path to:

```
 <img src="/img/logo.png" />
```

Comment: tried that.  same thing.  i even copied the image into every folder in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Firebug on the running page. It will let you change the path dynamically so that you can see if there is a problem with the path. Alternatively you can also just copy your dev path, say "`http://localhost:<someport>/img/logo.png`" and see whether it loads there.

As a third alternative you could use the `<asp:Image id="imageLoge" runat="server" ImageUrl="..."/>`. The advantage is that it will let you browse in the folders and select your image. In this way you're guaranteed that it is not a problem with your path.